# Mathematica calls NMinimize with symbols rather than numbers?

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I noticed the following behavior while using `NMinimize` in Mathematica. The first invocation of the objective function is with variable names, rather than with points from the space, as one would expect.

So for example if my objective function is a module, this module is called only once, evaluated symbolically and then in further iterations, this symbolic expression is evaluated with points from the variable space.

This behavior could slow down the computation significantly for a large expression.
Is there any way to get around this? Has anyone else experienced this? Is there any way to speed up `NMinimize` then?

Example:

```
dummy[x_] := Module[
  {},
  Print["x=", x ];
  4 x^4 - 4 x^2 + 1
  ]

In: NMinimize[dummy[x], x]
Out:x=x
{0., {x -> 0.707107}}
```

Comment: Depending on the module, this behaviour actually speeds up the evaluation. In the simple example you gave, it means that it only needs to make the function call once. But yes, for some functions, a symbolic or exact integer/rational (or exact numeric like `Pi` or `Sqrt[2]`) call can be incredibly slow. In which case restrict your function as suggested by @Mr.Wizard.

Comment: As an aside: it's interesting to note that `NMinimize[Unevaluated[dummy[x]], x]` calls `dummy` with `x=x` 4 times and never numerically.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried defining your function to only evaluate for numeric input?

```
dummy[x_?NumericQ] := ...
```

Comment: The reason for this is that `NMinimize` does not hold any of its arguments, so `dummy[x]` evaluates normally before it even gets into `NMinimize`-specific code.

Answer (score 2):

For some dummy functions an "exact numeric" call can also be very slow. Example finding the `FixedPoint[Sqrt,2.]` is fast, but `FixedPoint[Sqrt,2]` will go until something breaks!

By "exact numeric" I mean things like `Integers`, `Rationals`, and numeric symbolics like `Sqrt[2]`, `Cos[5]`, `Pi`, `EulerGamma`, etc...
that is, things that will return a numerical value when acted upon by `N[]`.

In this case it is probably better to use

```
dummy[_?InexactNumberQ] := ....
```

or even

```
dummy[_?MachineNumberQ] := ....
```

Comment: How would this compare to using `N` explicitly on arguments?

Comment: I prefer `NumericQ`, especially since adding `Element[x, Integers]` will fail with `InExactNumberQ` and setting `WorkingPrecision -> 20` will fail with `MachineNumberQ`.