# NMinimize eats all memory b/c of unnecessary symbolic work

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

The following code is a naive way to find the least number whose square has n divisors (the minimum should be its log and the x_i the powers in its prime factorization). If I look at the case n=2000 and use ten variables instead of twenty, this uses somewhere around 600MB of memory. With the value of n I'm actually trying to find the answer for, I need around 20 variables to be sure of not missing the actual solution, and it quickly uses up all available memory and then thrashes swap.

```
n=8*10^6;
a = Table[N[Log[Prime[i]]], {i, 20}];
b = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 20}];
cond = Fold[And, Product[2 Subscript[x, i] + 1, {i, 20}] > n,
   Table[Subscript[x, i] >= 0, {i, 20}]] && b \[Element] Integers;
NMinimize[{a.b, cond}, b, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

It turns out that the problem isn't related to integer programming etc at all (removing the restriction to the integers doesn't help).

My best guess is that the problem is that Mathematica is wasting all that memory expanding `Product[2 Subscript[x, i] + 1, {i, 20}]`. If I replace the product with just `Product[Subscript[x, i],{i,20}]` and change the constraints to be `>= 1` rather than `0` I get results without a hassle and without the kernel using more than 50MB of memory. (Though that preserves the inequality constraint and doesn't change the task of minimizing the objective function, it does mess up the integrality requirement- I get even results, which correspond to half-integers in the actual problem.)

[One person on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810588/mathematica-calls-nminimize-with-symbols-rather-than-numbers) had a similar problem; in their case, they had an objective function which was getting evaluated symbolically at a huge cost. They were able to remedy it by making the function only accept numeric input, effectively hiding it from Mathematica's "I have the Expand[] hammer, and everything looks like a nail" tendency. But you can't hide the constraint behind such a function (Mathematica will complain it's an invalid constraint).

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: I know the correct answer- after my Mathematica code didn't work I used AMPL and a dedicated MINLP solver to get it (quite quickly too). I just want to know how I can ever hope to be able to use Mathematica's built-in nonlinear optimization features in the future despite the crazy things it seems to do with my constraints when I enter them in the only way I know how.

Comment: j0ker5 seems to have found a solution for your _task_, but does that answer your _question_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can inhibit that condition from doing anything unless inputs are numeric, as below.

```
n = 8*10^6;
nvars = 20;
a = Table[N[Log[Prime[i]]], {i, nvars}];
b = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, nvars}];
c1[xx : {_?NumericQ ..}] := Times @@ (2 xx + 1);
c2 = Map[# >= 0 &, b];
c3 = b \[Element] Integers;
cond = Join[{c1[b] > n}, c2, {c3}];

In[29]:= Timing[NMinimize[{a.b, cond}, b, MaxIterations -> 400]]

Out[29]= {43.82100000000008, {36.77416664719056, {Subscript[x, 1] -> 
    3, Subscript[x, 2] -> 3, Subscript[x, 3] -> 2, 
   Subscript[x, 4] -> 2, Subscript[x, 5] -> 1, Subscript[x, 6] -> 1, 
   Subscript[x, 7] -> 1, Subscript[x, 8] -> 1, Subscript[x, 9] -> 1, 
   Subscript[x, 10] -> 1, Subscript[x, 11] -> 1, 
   Subscript[x, 12] -> 1, Subscript[x, 13] -> 0, 
   Subscript[x, 14] -> 0, Subscript[x, 15] -> 0, 
   Subscript[x, 16] -> 0, Subscript[x, 17] -> 0, 
   Subscript[x, 18] -> 0, Subscript[x, 19] -> 0, 
   Subscript[x, 20] -> 0}}}
```

---edit---

Thought I would point out that this can be set up as an integer linear programming problem. We use 0-1 variables for all possible combinations of primes and powers.

We can limit the number of primes using the fact that the solution cannot involve more primes than the minimum needed assuming all are raised to the first power. The objective is then minimal if they are consecutive starting at 2.

We will assume the max exponent is no more than 20. There is probably a convenient way to show this but it has not come to mind as yet.

The objective and constraints, in this formulation, are as below. We get a fully linear problem by taking logs of the divisor sigma equation.

```
n = 8*10^6;
nprimes = Ceiling[Log[2, n]];
maxexpon = 20;
vars = Array[x, {maxexpon, nprimes}];
fvars = Flatten[vars];
c1 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
c2 = {Element[fvars, Integers]};
c3 = Thread[Total[vars] <= 1];
c4 = {Total[N[Log[2*Range[maxexpon] + 1]].vars] >= N@Log[n]};
constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3, c4];
obj = Range[maxexpon].vars.N[Log[Prime[Range[nprimes]]]];

Timing[{min, vals} = NMinimize[{obj, constraints}, fvars];]

Out[118]= {5.521999999999991, Null}

Pick[fvars, fvars /. vals, 1] /. x[j_, k_] :> {Prime[k], j}

Out[119]= {{11, 1}, {13, 1}, {17, 1}, {19, 1}, {23, 1}, {29, 1}, {31, 
  1}, {37, 1}, {5, 2}, {7, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
```

This approach handles n=10^10 is around 23 seconds.

---end edit ---

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Looks like the key point with the way I was doing it is this: the condition can't _be_ a (boolean) function which is opaque to the symbolic eval, but it may _contain_ a function which is opaque to the symbolic eval. The alternate solutions to this problem were interesting, but realizing that even though you can't make the whole condition only accept numerics you can still keep the symbolic evaluation from happening is what will come in useful in lots of other optimization problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code instead:

```
Catch[Do[If[DivisorSigma[0, k^2] > 2000, Throw[k]], {k, 1000000}]]
```

which returns 180180.

---

#### ADDITION:

```
Catch[Do[If[Times@@(2 FactorInteger[k][[All, 2]] + 1) > 2000, Throw[k]], {k, 1000000}]]
```

Seems to work faster.

---

#### ADDITION 2:

Behold for this ultra-improved version (but not 100% proved):

```
MinSquareWithDivisors[n_] :=
 Min@Select[
   Product[Prime[k]^#[[k]], {k, 1, Length[#]}] & /@ 
    Flatten[IntegerPartitions /@ Range[Ceiling[Log[2, n]]], 1], 
   DivisorSigma[0, #^2] > n &]
```

`MinSquareWithDivisors[2000000000]` gives `2768774904222066200260800` in ~4 seconds

**Explanation**:

First of all one needs to prove that the sum of the prime's exponents in this minimum number is at most `Log[2, n]`. ***I haven't found a proof yet***, but it might be related to the ratio between successive primes.

`Flatten[IntegerPartitions /@ Range[Ceiling[Log[2, n]]], 1]` gives you all the lists with `Total <= Log[2, n]`, conveniently sorted from large to small.

`Product[Prime[k]^#[[k]], {k, 1, Length[#]}] &` use them as prime's exponents to create integers.

`Min@Select[..., DivisorSigma[0, #^2] > n &]` choose the minimal of them that agrees with the original condition.

Comment: Instead of Catch, Throw & Do, a simple While seems easier. You can stop at the lowest number that fits the criterion.

Comment: Yes, `Module[{k = 1}, While[DivisorSigma[0, k^2] < 2000, k++]; k]` is possible also.

Comment: EDIT: I've added another solution (labeled ADDITION 2) which is faster, but require a proof before using.

Comment: The correct answer for the case I care about- n=8*10^6- is 9350130049860600 (I got the answer by putting the problem in AMPL and using a dedicated MINLP solver). A solution that tries to avoid optimization routines by instead factoring the first 9.35E15 integers is not realistic.

Comment: I suppose the Prime Number Theorem could be used to help put an outside bound on my feasible set. Using the fact that the sequence of prime powers will be nonincreasing tightens the feasible set quite a bit, and might even make my specific case of n=8E6 brute-forceable. But really my question is more of "How can I use Mathematica's capabilities for nonlinear optimization despite the fact that it tends to do such stupid things to my constraints when I enter them the only way I know how" rather than "how can I get this specific answer."

Comment: No need to be frustrated on me. Anyway, I think that `NMinimize` is a problematic approach - It does not guarantee a global minimum in such cases.

Comment: Sorry- I certainly don't mean to sound like I'm frustrated with you; you've gone out of your way to put a good amount of thought towards my problem and  I appreciate that.